# Symbolic link to character device on Linux, mimic a regular file

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I've created a Linux character driver, which purpose is to provide some defaulted content with a randomness at a specific offset. The random portion is generated each time the device is read.

The point of doing this, is to provide a second application (consumer) with a bunch of symbolic links to this character device (generator), so the consumer can iterate over them and treat them like regular files with a different content. The problem is when the consumer checks for a size of these files, and since they are symbolic links to my generator, it thinks that they are empty and does nothing.

I'm aware that the character device might be a problem, because in fact it doesn't have a fixed length, even though I return only a specified portion of data.

I need something that will mimic the file size, or maybe should I use a different approach? I'm wondering if implementing this as a block device would change anything.

Comment: how is the consumer application checking for the size of the file ?

Comment: You could implement the `llseek` file operation, so that the appllication can use `SEEK_END` to determine the size. The `llseek` file operation handler can be pretty minimal. It just needs to call `fixed_size_llseek`.

Comment: @yashC: `st_size` method from Python's `os.stat`.
@IanAbbott: I've tried that, but with no luck. I've also tried: `generic_file_llseek_size` and `no_seek_end_llseek_size`.